# Group by within LISTAAG

Tags: amazon-redshift

Our database **postgresql** and were using `array_agg` function in one sql query to get  following output similar to

```
{"Basic:1","Basic:1","Basic:1","Basic:1","Basic:1","Basic:1","Paying:1","Paying:1","Paying:1"}
```

We have migrated to **redshift** and used `LISTAGG` function. It is fine if data is less and data is stored as

```
Basic:1,Basic:1,Basic:1,Basic:1,Basic:1,Basic:1,Paying:1,Paying:1,Paying:1
```

but we are getting following error if the dataset is large. -

```
Invalid operation: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit
```

Thing is that We need to achieve final result as `Basic:6,Paying:3`. Is there any alternate of LISTAGG?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your column you used in LISTAGG? LISTAGG can only handle up to 64K chars.

Documentation has this:

> VARCHAR(MAX). If the result set is larger than the maximum VARCHAR
>   size (64K – 1, or 65535), then LISTAGG returns the following error:
>
> ```
> Invalid operation: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit**
> ```

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html

Comment: Is there any option to limit that on the query?
Such an option exists for Oracle, couldn't find for redshift :/